# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html with css generated in PHP

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess

i have a site where the css is not interpreted. I've seen other answers but not one for a dinamically generated css. 
I'm generating the CSS in PHP by adding

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://tylldalil.wconsult.no/?ai1ec_render_css=1367403986&ver=3.5.1" id="ai1ec_stytle-css" rel="stylesheet">
```

my function in php

```
public function render_css() {
     header( 'Content-Type: text/css' );
    // Aggressive caching to save future requests from the same client.
    $etag = '"' . md5( __FILE__ . $_GET[self::GET_VARIBALE_NAME] ) . '"';
    header( 'ETag: ' . $etag );
    $max_age = 31536000;
    header(
        'Expires: ' .
        gmdate(
            'D, d M Y H:i:s',
            Ai1ec_Time_Utility::current_time() + $max_age
        ) .
        ' GMT'
    );
    header( 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=' . $max_age );
    if (
        empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) ||
        $etag !== stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] )
    ) {
        // compress data if possible
        if ( extension_loaded( 'zlib' ) ) {
            // ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' );
        }
        $content = $this->get_compiled_css();
        echo $content;
        ob_end_flush();
    } else {
        // Not modified!
        status_header( 304 );
    }
    // We're done!
    exit( 0 );
}
```

this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?tlldalil.wconsult.no$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ?page_id=23 [R=301,L]

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 88.89.104.103 
allow from 93.50.99.14



###Start Kloxo PHP config Area
###Please Don't edit these comments or the content in between. kloxo uses this to recognize the lines it writes to the the file. If the above line is corrupted, it may fail to recognize them, leading to multiple lines.

<Ifmodule mod_php4.c>
    php_value error_log "/home/klausen/__processed_stats/tylldalil.wconsult.no.phplog"
    php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
    php_value max_execution_time  60
    php_value max_input_time  120
    php_value memory_limit  64M
    php_value post_max_size  64M
    php_flag register_globals  off
    php_flag display_errors  off
    php_flag file_uploads  on
    php_flag log_errors  off
    php_flag output_buffering  off
    php_flag register_argc_argv  on
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc   off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime  off
    php_flag magic_quotes_sybase  off
    php_flag mysql.allow_persistent  off
    php_flag register_long_arrays  on
    php_flag allow_url_fopen  on
    php_flag cgi.force_redirect  on
    php_flag enable_dl  on
</Ifmodule>

<Ifmodule mod_php5.c>
    php_value error_log "/home/klausen/__processed_stats/tylldalil.wconsult.no.phplog"
    php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
    php_value max_execution_time  60
    php_value max_input_time  120
    php_value memory_limit  64M
    php_value post_max_size  64M
    php_flag register_globals  off
    php_flag display_errors  off
    php_flag file_uploads  on
    php_flag log_errors  off
    php_flag output_buffering  off
    php_flag register_argc_argv  on
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc   off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime  off
    php_flag magic_quotes_sybase  off
    php_flag mysql.allow_persistent  off
    php_flag register_long_arrays  on
    php_flag allow_url_fopen  on
    php_flag cgi.force_redirect  on
    php_flag enable_dl  on
</Ifmodule>

###End Kloxo PHP config Area




# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

What should i add to my htaccess?

Comment: Where is `render_css` called?

Comment: it's wordpress, but i see that the output of the call is corretc, it's just ignored. I have read that you could use addType, nut it needs a file extension

Comment: try to open http://tylldalil.wconsult.no/?ai1ec_render_css=1367403986&ver=3.5.1 in your browser. It is not CSS.

Comment: @claustrofob if i open it i see css. This is a server issue because it's working on thousands of other installs, the browser simply ignores it i think. Why do you say it's not css?
it's starting with .clearfix{*zoom:1;}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;content:"";}.
it's compressed oviously

Comment: if you see css the only problem might be with the content type returned by the server for this file. Can you check content type in firebug or devtools?

Comment: @claustrofob yes it's content tye, the question is how do i set the correct content type in apache?Because i'm setting it in PHP.
You won't see anything if you click the link because the access is restricted by apache

Answer (score 1):

When I try to view your CSS, I get an "Apache 2 Test Page powered by CentOS" HTML page instead. The page response headers declare "403 Forbidden".

Could this be connected to your aggressive caching?

What happens if, in your PHP, you amend the line:

```
$etag = '"' . md5( __FILE__ . $_GET[self::GET_VARIBALE_NAME] ) . '"';
```

to

```
$etag = '"' . md5( __FILE__ . $_GET[self::GET_VARIABLE_NAME] ) . '"';
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You set Content-type in php but it seems like server forces another Content-type for that script. You can try to set css extension for your script and rewrite it with mod_rewrite:

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://tylldalil.wconsult.no/css_1367403986_ver_3.5.1.css" id="ai1ec_stytle-css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule css_([0-9])+_ver_([0-9.]+)\.css$ ?ai1ec_render_css=$1&ver=$2 [E=FINISH:1,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ?page_id=23 [R=301,L]
```